# How do I perform a centered log-ratio transformation in R?

Tags: data-transformation

I have been struggling to find clearly described R code explaining how to input variables for the clr transformation in R. I only need to transform columns 20-201 in my dataset. Can anyone provide an example or 2? That would help tremendously. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Did you look at? https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/Hotelling/html/clr.html

Comment: The duplicate includes `R` code to compute the CLR.  The function `ilr` does this by default (and can be modified by using a non-default value of its second argument `p`).  You can find this and related posts by [searching our site for "CLR"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=clr%20is%3aanswer%20%5bR%5d)

Comment: I did see the CRAN page but I was confused about how to apply it since I only want to transform columns 20-201. Lets say call my dataset 'mydataset', but I only want certain columns transformed. So, here is the code:     clr(data, group = NULL)                                          Do I plug it in like this? clr(data(mydataset[,20:201]) , group = NULL)                           I tried this but it doesn't work